# Middleware auth redirects api routes to /home

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

I created api route:

File `routes/api.php:`

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 
function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() 
{
    Route::get('/tasks','TaskController@index');
});
```

After that I go to `/api/tasks`, middleware redirects to /home, what i should to do   to use /api/tasks without redirecting to /home(i am logged), and also i could to use this middleware?

Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completed with `laravel/passport`

Article: https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Answer (score 2):

When routes are placed in `api.php` it won't work if you're logged in via session to website. Actually it will be looking for API token which you're not sending now.

> If you're logged in via a session on the website, just hitting the API
>   endpoint isn't in your browser won't work. It won't be checking the
>   session to see if you're logged in, it will be looking for an API
>   token with the request. Since you aren't specifying a token, this
>   throws an AuthenticationException.
>
> The exception handler then takes this exception, checks your request
>   and sees that it hasn't specified in the headers that it expects JSON.
>   If it was expecting JSON, you would see a JSON response saying
>   unauthenticated. Since it isn't expecting JSON, it redirects to the
>   login page, which redirects to /home since you are logged in via a
>   session. Confusing, but I expect that's the reason.
>
> You'll need to use a tool like Postman if you want to play with your
>   API endpoints so you can specify the required headers in the request.

For more details visit [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/middlewareauthapi-redirect-home)

Comment: Nope, still redirected. I use header `Authorization : Basic my_token`. http://prnt.sc/mh9wxu

Comment: Instead of `auth:api` try using auth middleware!

Comment: Still redirects.

Comment: And postman transforms my token `x5kxNGTgSQyzYqRX59kun96tChATOiFKKgQi1N18lffv8GeEyurzmmHYmxku` to `YWFnejo=`